# Alternativa java para o code-climate

Tags: java, análise-estática

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma ferramenta/serviço para `Java` para o serviço [code-climate](https://codeclimate.com/)

O serviço proporciona uma análise do código sob diversos aspectos de boas práticas, potenciais riscos de segurança e [muitas outras coisas](https://codeclimate.com/tour/all-features). No entanto só está disponível para `Ruby on Rails`, `JavaScript` e `PHP`

No momento estou mais preocupado com a parte de análise estática do código. Sei que existem diversos plugins para diversas IDE mas estou procurando uma solução unificada, como, por exemplo, uma análise diretamente no repositório, sem depender de um ambiente uniformizado entre os desenvolvedores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias ferramentas conceituadas para análise estática e inspeção de qualidade do código em Java. Dentre elas:

- **[Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/):** Muito interessante para validar convenções de código e Javadoc. Nomes, quantidade de parâmetros em cada método, quantidade de linhas de código em um método, código duplicado, etc.
- **[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/):** Trabalha a nível de bytecode. É bem bacana para encontrar problemas com código (uso de `equals` vs `==`), concorrência, vulnerabilidade de código, internacionalização, entre outros.
- **[PMD](http://tirthalpatel.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/static-code-analyzers-checkstyle-pmd-findbugs.html):** Ferramenta com foco em detectar más práticas de codificação. Detecta problemas parecidos com os do FindBugs, mas a nível de código fonte (código morto, blocos `catch` vazios, etc). Consegue computar algumas métricas interessantes como complexidade ciclomática.
- **[SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/):** Ferramenta para inspeção de qualidade de código. Pode usar todas as ferramentas acima, bem como outras especializadas em testes de cobertura, testes unitários, etc. Possuí um *front end* web com relatórios, gráficos, evolução do código através do tempo, tendências, etc.

Todas essas ferramentas podem ser utilizadas fora do IDE (através do Ant, Maven, etc).

Para o seu caso recomendaria o SonarQube. Enquanto existem plugins para os principais IDES ([IDEA](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7238?pr=phpStorm), [Netbeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51532/radar-netbeans), [Eclipse](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse)), o SonarQube pode facilmente ser utilizado de maneira *stand-alone* e também junto as ferramentas de integração contínua mais comuns no mundo Java (Jenkins, Hudson, Bamboo, TeamCity, etc).

Comment: Valeu! Acho que sua recomendação vai servir perfeitamente! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução muito adequada:

- **[Codacy](https://www.codacy.com)**: faz inspeção de código (usa `PMD`) `commit a commit`, o que significa que numa base de código já existente continua a ser útil mesmo que não se queira/possa atacar todos os problemas já existentes (basta ir vendo as notificações atuais e agir sobre estas); apresenta bons relatórios e integra com uma série de ferramentas (`JIRA, Slack, Heroku, etc`); também é possível integrar soluções de Code `Coverage`. Também suporta outras linguagens (`JavaScript, Python, Ruby, PHP, Scala, CoffeeScript e CSS`) e apresenta documentação sobre como resolver cada um dos problemas que identifica.