# Code Metrics, Analysis e Clone para Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Galera, existe algo semelhante aos Code Metrics, Analysis e Clone do Visual Studio para o Android Studio? Sei que existe o Lint, mas até onde eu conheço ele não mede complexidade de código, código duplicado e etc.

Comment: Experimenta Sonar pode ser apropriado a tua situação http://www.sonarqube.org mas dá uma olhada neste projecto Quality Tools for Android https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android

Comment: Existe uma pergunta/resposta com alternativas de ferramentas de análise estática de código (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25690/alternativa-java-para-o-code-climate). Só precisa verificar se existe plugin para o Intellij, que é a base do Android Studio.

Comment: Valeu galera, vou fazer uns testes e volto a comentar aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço específico para Android, mas conheço esses dois para Java:

1. http://pmd.sourceforge.net/
2. http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/